# GWT: how to get FlexTable width?

Tags: gwt, flextable

Hello all) The task looked pretty easy - to get FlexTable's width and set this width to ScrollPanel to get rid of horizontal scrollbar - until I figured out that any method like table.getElement().getClientWidth() returns only 0.

Maybe smth wrong with the way I do it - I create table, fill it with data then call
int tableHeight = table.getElement().getClientWidth();
and this int is 0 despite the table itself looks normal in browser and its width 310 px.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get what width a flextable has, you can use:

```
table.getElement().getStyle().getWidth();
```

But that will only return the width that is set to it. To set a width, you can use:

```
table.setWidth();
```

**Note**: the `getWidth()` method will return whatever CSS `width` your table has, whether or not it was set programmatically.

Also, `getClientWidth()` would only give you the width of the table after it was attached to the parent widget, which is probably why it why it is returning 0 for you.

Comment: So, am I right - after attaching this table to scrollPanel its getClientWidth() should return the real width? I want to avoid hardcoding the width because my flextable is user-dependent so its size may vary for different users. The best would be populate it with data then get its size and put it in scrollpanel but I am not sure whether it is possible.